# Why it doesn't pick up any cameras?

Tags: c#, camera, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm in making barcode scanner but "VideoCaptureDevice can't pick up any objects" ? 
I'm using AForge video and ZXing in visual studio 2019 C#
I want it to be able to scan barcodes from my laptop webcam.
I tried running it with the problem but in my combobox where are supposed to be cameras available for use but they are none. I even tried activating the webcam before opening up the program.
code:

```
        FilterInfoCollection FilterInfoCollection;
        VideoCaptureDevice VideoCaptureDevice;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FilterInfoCollection = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            foreach (FilterInfo device in FilterInfoCollection)
                comboBox1.Items.Add(device.Name);
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            VideoCaptureDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(FilterInfoCollection[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
            VideoCaptureDevice.NewFrame += VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame;
            VideoCaptureDevice.Start();
        }

        private void VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
            var result = reader.Decode(bitmap);
            if (result != null)
            {
                textBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
                {
                    textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
                }));

            }
            pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (VideoCaptureDevice != null)
            {
                if (VideoCaptureDevice.IsRunning)
                    VideoCaptureDevice.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I keep getting this error msg: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an object instance.

Comment: Ok, i have checked it more deeply.This error is thrown from those nuget packages. So to find solution You need to debug them